# Can I use a local::lib if local::lib isn't installed globally and without eval-ing it in shell?

Tags: perl, locallib

I have a problem, I want to `use local::lib;` in a script. But because I need to use this script many places, I don't want to try adding the `eval` to `bashrc`, every time I install this script to a server. and I can't get [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) installed globally (in the default `@INC`) on the servers. Is there any way I can `use local::lib` from within the script so that it knows where the module `local::lib` is without the `eval` that `local::lib` recommends and without installing it into a directory in the default `@INC` on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this at the top of your script should work, though I have local::lib installed on all my boxes in the regular @INC so it's untested–

```
use lib "/path/to/local/lib's/lib";
use local::lib "/path/to/specific/local-lib/base/you/want";
```

I would recommend having local::lib installed the same way, in the default @INC with your main env perl. The various local repositories it can create are not tied to its location proper.

Comment: obviously that would be ideal, however convincing $dayjob that it should be rolled out on our thousands of servers.... I will investigate this as a possible solution though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know at least where local::lib was installed, and you won't get around specifying this, so you need one shell command or environment variable declaration. Assuming you used the default for `--bootstrap`, this is a minimal example in bash for Perl to find the library:

```
# persistent for this shell only
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:$(perl -MConfig -e'print "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5/$Config{archname}:$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5"')
perl yourprog
perl yourprog
perl yourprog
```

or just

```
# environment for one run of perl only
PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:$(perl -MConfig -e'print "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5/$Config{archname}:$ENV{HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5"') perl yourprog
```

It is safe to simply hard-code the directory names and thus avoid the eval and call to perl.

`use local::lib;` will find and load the module from the extended `@INC`. Inspect `%INC` to see the specific location if you actually need that.

Caveat: You cannot use local::lib now to *install* additional modules, that needs the rest of the declarations made in the usual eval it prints out.

---

Setting environment vars from within with the reexecution trick as per urgh below.

```
use autodie qw(:all);
unless ($ENV{REEXEC}) {
    $ENV{REEXEC} = 1;
    $ENV{PERL5LIB} = …
    exec $^X, $0;
}
# main starts here
```

Comment: urgh, I was hoping for something that could be done from within the perl script.

Comment: Oh, that's a neat trick.  A trick I am *positive* it's a bad thing for me to know.